# Multiple WebClients ( Spring webflux ) for multiple hosts

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux

In my application, I am calling 4 different apis ( all on different hosts ). I would like to have a separate connection pool for each of the host and other parameters ( eg. keep alive, etc. ). Can I achieve this using a single WebClient or do I need 4 different WebClient instances for this?

Also, does it make sense to have a separate connection pool for each host? If not, Can I achieve this using single WebClient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on the underlying HTTP library being used by Spring WebFlux. Right now Spring is supporting Reactor Netty (the default) and Jetty client.

By default, the `WebClient` will have a single connection pool; connections are reused based on the host+port key and the `reactor.netty.resources.ConnectionProvider` will be elastic, meaning it will never wait to open a new connection. You can configure your own and set the maximum number of connections to a fixed value.

As far as I know, the keepAlive and all TCP-related options are handled at the TCP level with `io.netty.channel.ChannelOption`. I don't think you can change those on a per host basis nor on a per-connection pool basis, since they belong to the event loop resources.

Other clients, like Jetty, might provide different options, but I assume that you're using the default one here.

I don't see any strong reason to have a connection pool per host. What we're usually trying to achieve is maximum resource utilization. For example in Spring Boot, we're auto-configuring things so that the server and the client (in the same application) are reusing the same resources. Since some of those are tied to the number of CPU cores, reusing the same ones improves efficiency overall.

There are many TCP-related options, and unless you have a very specific problem to solve, I think the defaults should be kept as a lot of thoughts were put into those.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Where can I find the default values for connection pooling?